# Is there an alternate term for "the power behind the throne?"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

*NOAD* describes a *[figurehead](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/figurehead?q=figurehead)* as

> a nominal leader or head without real power.

I'm wondering if there's a complementary one-word term for the person who *does* wield the power in such a situation. I'm aware of the phrase, *[power behind the throne](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/power?q=power%20behind%20the%20throne#power__31)*,

> a person or organization that exerts authority or influence without having formal status.

I'm just hoping there's a way to refer to such a person more directly and succinctly.

Comment: From *The Wizard of Oz,* there's *the man behind the curtain.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though ***kingmaker*** originally meant the person with power to influence the choice of prince, it is also now used in a larger sense of power behind the throne.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using French, and if you can accept two words, there's *éminence grise*.

Comment: Which, unfortunately, has come to mean [elder statesman](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%C3%A9minence%20grise) in current usage; otherwise, _éminence grise_ captures it perfectly.

Comment: @Gnawme: There is no such suggestion in the OED's definition and citations. I suppose the association with age, if there is one, has come about through understanding 'grise' as 'grey-haired'.

Comment: Perhaps it's an American perversion. When I consult [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), about 5 of the 25 results appear to use the term in the sense of "power behind the throne."

Answer (score 3):

***puppet master*** as they are pulling strings of a *puppet*

Answer (score 1):

*Éminence grise* hits the mark pretty closely: anyone who has great influence, usually over a figurehead, such as a pontiff or (henpecked) husband without being observed much in that role. *The Hidden Hand* conveys the same idea.

Comment: "The Hidden Hand". Are you referring here to the *invisible hand*, Adam Smith's coinage?