# What is the English counterpart to the Japanese ‘Insei’ – rule by a retired emperor/leader?

Tags: single-word-requests

There was a following statement in Time magazine’s article (February 25) titled “Second Act” dealing with the step-down of the former Pope Benedict XVI:

> The new Pope will be indebted to Benedict XVI. -- and even though he
>   won't be in the Sistine Chapel when the voting takes place, Benedict
>   is bound to influence the outcome. This sort of informal influence has
>   proved powerful in other cultures--particularly premodern Japan, where
>   retired shoguns and Emperors continued to make pivotal decisions.
>   Thus, just by watching from the sidelines, Ratzinger will be subtly
>   able to champion his conservative theological and social policies--an
>   über-Pope of sorts.

This statement is true. Actually many incumbent Emperors were just nominal and powerless in Japan during the Middle Ages and controlled by retired emperors behind the curtain.

We call this “informal influence“ of the retired ruler or leader including chairman of a company ‘Insei – 院政 in Japanese, and ‘Readers English Japanese Dictionary’ at hand translates ‘Insei’ to ‘rule by a retired emperor – insei.”

Although Readers Dictionary shows the word “Insei,” as if it is already adopted to English language like 'Mikado' or ‘Shogun,’ I doubt its currency as an English word.

With that said, what is the English counterpart of “Insei” in shorter form, say two words, than “rule by a cloistered emperor”?

Comment: [*Power behind the throne; eminence grise*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56327/is-there-an-alternate-term-for-the-power-behind-the-throne)

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross: as close as that is, doesn't that refer to a non-ruler, say a regent or important civil servant unlikely to actually be such  a nominal ruler, as opposed to a former ruler?

Comment: @Mitch That's why it's a comment; but a former ruler is at least nominally a non-ruler. English doesn't have a direct equivalent for *insei* because "rule by a retired monarch" is rather rare: most cause succession by dying! However, a retired/deselected prime minister could well still be the power behind his successor's throne.

Comment: "Emeritus" is informally used with that meaning. You could refer to Benedict as the "Pope emeritus." I think the proper use of the term applies only to faculty of educational institutions, though.

Comment: The Vatican has, in fact, decreed that Benedict is to be titled "pope emeritus" or "emeritus pope". That's not terribly relevant to this question, though. What Yoichi-san seems to want is a counterpart to *regency*, except on the other end of a reign. The problem is, the historical English term for a former king is "dead".

Comment: Didn't one abdicate?

Comment: @Yoichi, Does the Japanese term have a sinister component, or is it more titular?

Comment: The word, Insei has a negative tone to us, because the puppet government or management doesn’t function well. In the Middle Ages, there were succession of incumbent Emperors being ruled by former (retired) emperors in Japan which resulted in chaos of politics and governance and misery of populace. Insei still applies to Japanese corporation today. Ex-presidents try to influence on Presidents by keeping power even after being shelved up to Chairman, which causes internal feuding very often.

Comment: It will be very difficult, if not impossible, to come up with a satisfactory answer to this question because it is very likely that an "English counterpart of 'Insei' in shorter form, say two words," does not in fact exist; and if this is so, it is because we in the West have not really had any need for such a term, since such a phenomenon as @Yoichi Oishi describes has been absent, or very nearly so, from our history. I think that Diocletian at Spalato and Charles V at Yuste are as close as we may approach, and it is not quite certain that they actually "ruled" while in retirement.

Comment: This doesn't really help come up with a word, but perhaps there was a Russian *insei* in the form of Putin while Medvedev was president from 2008-2012?

Comment: As for the actual question, it seems to me that this is a case where no concise expression exists in English, and we should just borrow the Japanese *insei*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want “elder statesman”, sometimes used to refer to a retired politician (especially one whom the current leaders consult).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single word, there is an adjective that refers to the idea of "ex-ruler" and a phrase that refers to an insidious control.

First, the notion of ex-ruler:

> emeritus

has a Latin [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=emeritus), and incidentally became the official title for the retired pope.

The most common usage is in *professor emeritus*, who although retired, may bring considerable influence to bear, but is relieved of his more public duties (such as lecturing).

(Props to St John of the Cross.) The phrase

> éminence grise

historically does not refer to an ex-ruler [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89minence_grise), but carries the connotation of an insidious control.

Comment: Hi Rajah. I don't see how this answers the question. Yoichi-san wasn't asking what Benedict will be called, but what the English term is for retired kings who advise the current king.

Comment: The title "Pope Emeritus" was announced on February 26 and is a matter of record. *Emeritus* simply means "retired". This doesn't answer the question, though, which is about a rule by influence; almost a clandestine affair.

Comment: I think one difference is that in Europe, kings have never officially retired.

Comment: @PeterShor Well, Edward VIII did; and several Queens of the Netherlands have too. But constitutional monarchies have more safeguards against eminences grises than absolute monarchies.

Comment: Thanks you for the comments. While I understand the reasons for the downvote, *emeritus* is a neutral title that conveys both the notions of being relieved of duty, yet retaining influence. Of note is that this was indeed the announced title (thanks,  @StJohnoftheCross, I did not know that). The OP said in comments that *insei* has a sinister connotation, but *emeritus* does not connote that. I'm thinking *éminence grise* is closer. Perhaps St John of the Cross should proffer it as an answer, instead of as a comment?

Comment: I believe I have also seen *grey eminence* (the literal translation of *eminence grise*) used for this.

Comment: ‘Eminence-grise’ might be close to Insei in terms of someone influencing on or manipulating the incumbent Emperor or King from the behind-the-scenes. But from its origin as the nickname of Père Joseph, French monk and diplomat, confidant of Cardinal Richelieu who was known as Éminence Rouge; eminence grise’ was a subordinate to the Cardinal, while the wielder of Insei is the ex-emperor who actually held and still holds power. Can ‘Eminence-grise’ be used for an ex-supremacy, not his follower?

Comment: @YoichiOishi, it seems as though *insei* would be split between the two terms. If you are referring to ex-supremacy, then *emeritus* works better. If you are referring to the insidious, manipulative qualities, then *éminence grise* works better. But I don't think that one English word encompasses both.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the closest equivalent is **puppet government**:

> a government which is endowed with the outward symbols of authority
>   but in which direction and control are exercised by another power [M-W
>   Unabridged]

If you wanted to coin a term, you could call it a *puppetocracy*.

Comment: A puppet is an object manipulated by a puppeteer, who could be liken to a retired Emperor or leader.To me, puppet government seems to be the object or the opposite word to 'Insei' rather than its equvalent..

Comment: It follows from this definition of _puppet_: "one whose acts are controlled by an outside force or influence" [M-W]

Comment: BTW, Google Translate renders 院政 in English as "cloister government."